# How do I populate Ansible variables in a single pass

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a simple Ansible role which creates a Foreman activation key, however it only "subscriptions" with the last value and not both?

```
# cat roles/hammer/tasks/subscription.yml
---

- name: Add Subscription key ID to Activation Key
  katello_activation_key:
    username: "{{ hammer.username|default('NotSet') }}"
    password: "{{ hammer.password|default('NotSet') }}"
    server_url: "https://{{ system_host_name }}"
    name: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    organization: "{{ hammer.organisation.name }}"
    lifecycle_environment: "{{ item.0.lifecycle }}"
    content_view: '{{ item.0.cview }}'
    subscriptions:
      - name: "{{ item.1 }}"
  #   - name: "{{ item.1.name2 }}"
    auto_attach: False
    release_version: Initial
  tags: hammer
...
```

My vars file contains:

```
act_key:
  - name: CentOS 7 content Development Key
    desc: CentOS 7 content Development Key
    release: Initial
    cview: CentOS 7 content
    lifecycle: Development
  #  subscription: ['CentOS-7','CentOS-7-EPEL']
    subscription:
      - CentOS-7
      - CentOS-7-EPEL

  - name: CentOS 7 content Production Key
    desc: CentOS 7 content Production Key
    cview: CentOS 7 content
    release: Initial
    lifecycle: Production
  #  subscription: ['CentOS-7','CentOS-7-EPEL']
    subscription:
      - CentOS-7
      - CentOS-7-EPEL

  - name: CentOS 8 content Development Key
    desc: CentOS 8 content Development Key
    cview: CentOS 8 content
    release: Initial
    lifecycle: Development
  #  subscription: ['CentOS-8','CentOS-8-EPEL']
    subscription:
      - CentOS-8
      - CentOS-8-EPEL

  - name: CentOS 8 content Production Key
    desc: CentOS 8 content Production Key
    cview: CentOS 8 content  
    release: Initial
    lifecycle: Production
  #  subscription: ['CentOS-8','CentOS-8-EPEL']
    subscription:
      - CentOS-8
      - CentOS-8-EPEL
```

I am trying to to add " subscription: ['CentOS-7','CentOS-7-EPEL']" in a single pass as if I use the "with_subelements" loop only the last item "CentOS-7-EPEL" or "CentOS-8-EPEL" is added (and not both).

Can anyone suggest a way to change my variables file or play to make the katello_activation_key add both variables in a single pass?

Comment: You loop over something in your task, could you please add that loop to see, what you mean with item.0 and item.1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First the list of dictionaries in `act_key` contains a key `subscription` and that value is a list. So you don't need to iterate over multiple lists

```
- name: Add Subscription key ID to Activation Key
  katello_activation_key:
    ..
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    organization: "{{ hammer.organisation.name }}"
    lifecycle_environment: "{{ item.lifecycle }}"
    content_view: '{{ item.cview }}'
    subscriptions: "{{ item.subscription }}"
    ...
  loop: "{{ act_key }}"
```

Second - the `katello_activation_key.subscriptions` doesn't allow a string list (but also a list of dict with a single key `name`) - so you can use [dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) or [items2dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries) to create a map/dict of the list of the names. But I would prefer to change the `act_key` for better reading to contain the same format in subscription, then ´katello_activation_key` needs.